# When is ActionController.HttpContext set?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to implement an ASP.NET Core MVC web app similar to Jason Taylor's [CleanArchitecture](https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture) design. In the WebUi "layer" I try to implement an abstraction of an `IIdentityService` in which I want to access the [ClaimsPrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal?view=net-6.0) associated with the current `HttpRequest`.

After some digging through the source code on github, I found that the `Controller.User` property stems from [ControllerBase](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs).HttpContext? which is derived from [ControllerContext](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerContext.cs) which in turn is derived from [ActionContext](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions/ActionContext.cs) in which the `HttpContext` property is defined as

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the <see cref="Http.HttpContext"/> for the current request.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// The property setter is provided for unit test purposes only.
/// </remarks>
public HttpContext HttpContext
{
    get; set;
}
```

Here I am hitting a dead end. I assume the property is initialised by some middleware (ie. .AddAuthentication() / .AddAuthorization() from Microsoft.Identity), but I would like to confirm that, so I know how to get a reference to that object in my service.

Other sources of `IPrincipal`s, from which `ClaimsPrincipal` I have found are

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User
ClaimsPrincipal.Current
Thread.CurrentPrincipal

IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
var principal = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User;
```

with the documentation for [IHttpContextAccessor here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-6.0), but I cannot figure out which is the one `Controller.User` is pointing to.

Comment: Is your "service" a singleton? Then you have a challenge... the HttpContext is set every request. You can access it from your controllers (which are also created every request) as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-httpcontext-from-a-controller)

Comment: @JHBonarius Is is scoped and injected into the core where it is used in commands (CQRS) to create / delete / ... principals and/ or injected into controllers where it is used to query the principal whether `Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

Comment: If you inject your scoped service into the controller, it will have the same scope as the controller, thus the same IHttpContextAccessor. All per request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being hinted in the right direction by @JHBonarius in the comments, I found a documented case in [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components)

> #### Use HttpContext from custom components
>
> For other framework and custom components that require access to
> HttpContext, the recommended approach is to register a dependency
> using the built-in Dependency Injection (DI) container. The DI
> container supplies the IHttpContextAccessor to any classes that
> declare it as a dependency in their constructors:
>
> ```
> var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
>
> builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
> builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
> builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
> ```
>
> ###### In the following example:
>
> UserRepository declares its dependency on IHttpContextAccessor. The
> dependency is supplied when DI resolves the dependency chain and
> creates an instance of UserRepository.
>
> ```
> public class UserRepository : IUserRepository {
>     private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
>
>     public UserRepository(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) =>
>         _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
>
>     public void LogCurrentUser()
>     {
>         var username = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
>
>         // ...
>     } 
> }
> ```